# ADAL for Windows Store SSO

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adal

How do I implement SSO with ADFS?

I try to setup SSO from a Windows Store App that is deployed locally with a Developer license on a Tablet that is domain joined (Win 8.1 Pro) but the login dialog of ADFS is shown. I would like that SSO takes over and that the token is automatically provided by the authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync method. 
The ADFS is deployed to federate an on-premise Active Directory.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/10/adal-v2-and-windows-integrated-authentication/ should do what you are looking for.
HTH!
V.